# Using javascript for opening a form after pressing a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my first time using javascript and I am trying to open a form after I click a button. After looking at posts here and trying to do this on my own I cannot get this to work. Whenever I click the button, nothing shows up.
Can anyone help remedy this issue?

Below is the section of my index.php file that I am trying to do this in

```
<button class="advanced-search" id="adv-search-btn">Advanced Search</button>
        <div class="advanced-search-box"  id="advanced-search-box">
            <form>
                <input id="searchA" class="searchbox6" type="text" placeholder="% of A's" name="num_A">
                <input id="searchAminus" class="searchbox7" type="text" placeholder="% of A-'s" name="num_Aminus">
                <input id="searchBplus" class="searchbox8" type="text" placeholder="% of B+'s" name="num_Bplus">
                <input id="searchB" class="searchbox9" type="text" placeholder="% of B's" name="num_B">
                <input id="searchBminus" class="searchbox10" type="text" placeholder="% of B-'s" name="num_Bminus">
                <input id="searchCplus" class="searchbox11" type="text" placeholder="% of C+'s" name="num_Cplus"> 
                <input id="searchC" class="searchbox12" type="text" placeholder="% of C's" name="num_C">
                <input id="searchCminus" class="searchbox13" type="text" placeholder="% of C-'s" name="num_Cminus">
            </form>
        </div>

        <script>
            var advSearchBtn = document.getElementbyID("adv-search-btn");
            var advancedSearchBox = document.getElementbyID("advanced-search-box");

            advSearchBtn.onclick = function(){
                advancedSearchBox.style.display = "block";
            }

        </script>
```

And in the CSS file i have

```
.advanced-search-box{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: If you open your browser console you should be able to see errors. One of which being `getElementbyID` is not a function. Make sure you use the case correctly `getElementById`. I suggest you try and fix any other issues you see in the bworser console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check dev tool for errors; it seems that you typed the wrong case for `document.getElementById`.
You used `document.getElementbyID` which is incorrect.

The correct case with demo is below;

```
var advSearchBtn = document.getElementById("adv-search-btn");
var advancedSearchBox = document.getElementById("advanced-search-box");
```

```css
.advanced-search-box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="advanced-search" id="adv-search-btn">Advanced Search</button>
<div class="advanced-search-box" id="advanced-search-box">
  <form>
    <input id="searchA" class="searchbox6" type="text" placeholder="% of A's" name="num_A">
    <input id="searchAminus" class="searchbox7" type="text" placeholder="% of A-'s" name="num_Aminus">
    <input id="searchBplus" class="searchbox8" type="text" placeholder="% of B+'s" name="num_Bplus">
    <input id="searchB" class="searchbox9" type="text" placeholder="% of B's" name="num_B">
    <input id="searchBminus" class="searchbox10" type="text" placeholder="% of B-'s" name="num_Bminus">
    <input id="searchCplus" class="searchbox11" type="text" placeholder="% of C+'s" name="num_Cplus">
    <input id="searchC" class="searchbox12" type="text" placeholder="% of C's" name="num_C">
    <input id="searchCminus" class="searchbox13" type="text" placeholder="% of C-'s" name="num_Cminus">
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  var advSearchBtn = document.getElementById("adv-search-btn");
  var advancedSearchBox = document.getElementById("advanced-search-box");

  advSearchBtn.onclick = function() {
     /*
     if(advancedSearchBox.style.display != "block"){
        advancedSearchBox.style.display = "block";
     }else{
        advancedSearchBox.style.display = "none";
     }*/

     advancedSearchBox.style.display = advancedSearchBox.style.display === "block" ? "none" : "block";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: thank you that was the issue! Now if i wanted to open the form when clicking the button, but also close the form (when the form is open) by clicking the same button, any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: @vivekh99 you could add an if statement to check the value of display property. I updated the answer and demo.

Comment: @Jerdine, the ternary operator looks better :) advancedSearchBox.style.display = advancedSearchBox.style.display === "block" ? "none" : "block";

Answer (score 2):

Vivek, adding to Jerdine's Answer for your question "How to toggle the state ie, open and close", change the below code

```
 advancedSearchBox.style.display = "block";
```

to

```
advancedSearchBox.style.display = advancedSearchBox.style.display === "block" ? "none" : "block";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

visibility: hidden;

then

```
advSearchBtn.onclick = function(){
advancedSearchBox.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```